# Not getting actual MAC Address of the system

Tags: c#, asp.net, mac-address

I am using `NetworkInterface` class to get my system's `MAC Address`, here is the code

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {

            // Only consider Ethernet network interfaces, thereby ignoring any
            // loopback devices etc.
            if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet &&
                nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
        }
```

on my system I am getting my system's `MAC Address` but on other systems I am getting my Tunnel's adapter physical address 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0, and not able to get actual `MAC Address` of the system. Can you please help me to figure out the issue and also discribe why this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see system can have multiple MAC adresses, so you will not get your system MAC Address. You can get MAC address of certain interface. So this Tunnel adapter is Ethernet adapter and is up, so you have to narrow your filtering to interface which you want to get address.

So you have to filter by `Name` or `Id` also, or you have to use list of MAC addresses and drop anything that looks like invalid value "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0".

Not mac adress by name or id but network interface:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=vs.110).aspx

There is field called `Name` and field called `Id` so:

```
if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet &&
                nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && !nic.Name.Contains("Tunnel"))
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
```

Comment: how will I filter the mac addresses by their ID or Name, can you please provide me the code for this.

Comment: Updated answer, check out MSDN link I have provided. To filter out tunnel interfaces !nic.Name.Contains("Tunnel") you can also add !nic.Name.Contains("VirtualBox") to filter out virtualbox adapters.